Flink SQL JDBC to Oracle BLOB column
The source is MySQL, there is a BLOB field, and the sink is Oracle and the field type is BLOB. When using the upsert method, the BLOB field cannot be inserted. The error is
ORA-01461: Only the LONG value to be inserted into the LONG column can be bound.

Flink SQL：
create table t_test_table
(
    wid  STRING ,
    name STRING ,
    photos BYTES,
    PRIMARY KEY (wid) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH  (
         'connector' = 'jdbc',
          'url' = '***',
          'table-name' = 't_test_table',
          'username' = '***',,
          'password' = '***',
       );

create table t_test_table_bak
(
    wid  STRING ,
    name STRING ,
    photos BYTES,
    PRIMARY KEY (wid) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'jdbc',
    'url' = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:...',
    'table-name' = 't_test_table_bak',
    'username' = ''***',',
    'password' = ''***','
);
INSERT INTO t_test_table_bak SELECT wid, name, photos FROM t_test_table;

The SQL corresponding to upsert mode is :
MERGE INTO t_test_table_bak t  USING (SELECT :wid wid, :name name, :photos photos FROM DUAL) s  ON (t.wid=s.wid)  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.name=s.name, t.photos=s.photos WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (wid, name, photos) VALUES (s.wid, s.name, s.photos)

How should I deal with this situation? Thanks.

Oracle does not have a BYTES data type. It looks like whatever you are using is creating the Oracle table with a LONG column and not a BLOB. Please [edit] the question and include the output of SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name IN ('T_TEST_TABLE', 'T_TEST_TABLE_BAK') showing the actual data-type of the Oracle table.

BYTES is a type in flink sql, corresponding to Oracle's blob. I also tried the LONG type and the same error occurred

What is the data type of the columns in the Oracle database?

the date type is BLOB.
